# How can I check if a particular partition ext4 is journaled?

Tags: partitioning, ext4

I need to know this because of this:

> Add the data=writeback mounting option if you formatted the disk without journaling. Otherwise add data=ordered which sould be a good compromise between full journaling and none at all.

from the [SSDChecklist](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MagicFab/SSDchecklist).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda1 | more`, look for a line starting with *Filesystem Features*, should say **has_journal**.

To turn off journal and speed things up on a ext4 partition follow these steps:

**Example uses sda1 device, this does not mean you should do it on your main disk, replace sda1 with the disk you are preparing, data loss will happen!**

Create ext4 fs on /dev/sda1 disk

`mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1`

To enable `writeback` mode use this. This mode will typically provide the best ext4 performance.

`tune2fs -o journal_data_writeback /dev/sda1`

To delete journal remove has_journal option, this will disable etx4 journal

`tune2fs -O ^has_journal /dev/sda1`

Check if everything is ok

`e2fsck -f /dev/sda1`

Done, recommended for speed applications only! Gl

Answer (score 19):

The following command executed as superuser, and using as a parameter the correct partition

```
debugfs -R features /dev/sda1
```

should give you an output like the following

```
debugfs 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
Filesystem features: has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
```

where you can read `has_journal`.

Comment: One way to find out whether the journaling level is "ordered", "writeback", or "journal" is to run `dmesg | grep 'mounted filesystem'`, a tip from [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=104254). The documentation on ext4 mentions [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ext4/journal.html) and [here](https://mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt) that "ordered" is the default journaling level.

Answer (score 8):

`tune2fs -l /dev/sdaX | grep features` (from [linuxquestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/idenitfying-current-ext3-journal-mode-698738/#post4580618))