# How to remove has_journal feature on primary disk

Tags: 14.04, vmware, ext4, ext3

I'm running a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a VMware virtual machine and I'd like to disable journaling feature on the primary disk.

I did find [this useful post](https://askubuntu.com/a/76925/287769) but I can't use it because it says

```
The has_journal feature may only be cleared when the filesystem is
unmounted or mounted read-only.
```

Am I SOL or can there be some workaround ? Maybe some sort of 'Safe-Mode' boot?

Thanks!

Comment: Boot your virtual machine with an ubuntu.iso and run the commands from there. In general, I would advise against this ;)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen it'd be nice if you could elaborate :) i.e any version would do? how would I "find" my root directory etc, why would you advise against it (currently I don't have a choice but it's just interesting)?

Comment: Why disable the fileystem journaling feature?.....Journaling greatly helps ensure the integrity of your filesystem.

Comment: @mdpc well because this is part of a certain thing I'm currently doing and I *have* to do it, the question is just what is the easiest way to accomplish that.
I'm not arguing that it's a good or bad thing to do, it's a requirement (and no arguing with the bad journaling hating people **will not work** :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) for instructions on booting into recovery mode (I'm not sure how this applies to a VM session):

1. Press and hold the shift key after the bios has finished to bring up GRUB
2. Pick the "Advanced options" line
3. Find the entry for your kernel version that ends in "(recovery mode)"
4. After a few moments, another menu with some options will appear.  Select "Drop to a root shell prompt"

At this point, you'll have shell access as root and your root partition will be mounted read-only.  This should allow you to clear the journal on this partition.